# Why is it necessary to run both mongod and mongo.exe in windows? What's happening behind the scene?

Tags: mongodb, windows, mongodb-3.4

Why is it necessary to run both mongod and mongo.exe in windows? What's happening behind the scene?

What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

As @Stennie explained it's exactly the other way around .. mongod is the daemon background process running the database server and mongo.exe is the interactive shell.

As such - both are running if you want to use the database from the command prompt / a console [CMD] window.

Comment: FYI `mongod` is the server daemon and `mongo` (aka the `mongo` shell) is the client console tool.